# How to deny access to my server except certain hosts and IPs with Apache 2.4+

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, https, dns

By reverse IP search, I found that there are two other domain names (not mine) bound to my server's IP, which hosts my website. I just want to stop visitors from visiting my website by these two domain names. have tried many methods but all of them do not works at all. Here are some methods I have tried.

1. Add these lines at beginning of /etc/apache2/sites-available/haichaoyu.com.conf:

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName catchall
        <Location />
           Order Deny,Allow
           Deny from all
        </Location>
   </VirtualHost>

   <VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName catchall
        <Location />
           Order Deny,Allow
           Deny from all
        </Location>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
2. Add these lines in /var/www/haichaoyu.com/public_html/.htaccess

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^haichaoyu\.com$
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.haichaoyu\.com$
   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^former\.haichaoyu\.com$
   RewriteRule ^ - [F]
   ```

In addition, I have forced all http traffic to https traffic. And now I have three domains: haichaoyu.com, www.haichaoyu.com, former.haichaoyu.com.

Could anyone give me some help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Why don't you delete the DNS record for the 2 domain name ?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Hi. Now, you can visit my website by haichaoyu.com, mojo.vn or mobius.vn. What I want to do is to stop visitors from visiting my website by the  unauthorized domains (mobius.vn and mojo.vn).

Comment: @naurel The other two domains are not mine: movius.vn and mojo.vn

Comment: You could set up the virtualHost correctly with the desired domain spelled explicitly.  `<VirtualHost haichaoyu.com:80>`, `ServerName haichaoyu.com` etc.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I tried it and It does not works

Comment: Ah, ok, apparently  `*:80` is the default way to go. I misremembered. https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/examples.html shows a configuration example. The first VirtualHost is the default and catches all the requests except for `example.org`. So you want to set up haichaoyu.com as the second Virtualhost

Comment: @Pekka웃  I added these lines to the beginning of haichaoyu.com.conf. But It still doesn't work. It is amazing!!
<VirtualHost *.vn:80>
     ServerName catchall
     <Location />
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
     </Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *.vn:443>
     ServerName catchall
     <Location />
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from all
     </Location>
</VirtualHost>